# Array of Array(containing object) in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a Array of Array containing objects,

Here is my code,

```
var objA = new Array();

function myFunction(){
     objA ['1'] = new Array();
     objA ['1'].push({'bird':'parrot','animal':'rabbit'});
     var item = objA ['1'];
     alert(item['bird']);
}
```

Now ideally above code should alert 'parrot', but instead I get 'undefined'.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `objA` is an array but you're passing a string "index", which will work but unexpectedly. Use an object instead, `{}`. Btw, you can declare an array simply as `[]`.

Comment: Sounds like you'd rather want an array of objects instead of an array of arrays of objects.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the attribute to a new array:

```
objA ['1'] = new Array();
```

So, of course, when you retrieve it, *you're getting back an array*.

```
var item = objA ['1'];
```

Arrays don't have a `bird` attribute. The first item in the array does, though.

```
alert(item[0]['bird']);
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use:

```
var item = objA ['1'][0];
```

When you do `objA ['1'].push(..)` you are **appending** an item to the array `objA ['1']` - whose items should be referenced by index like `objA ['1'][0]`, `objA ['1'][1]` etc..

Answer (score 1):

Always `console.log(anything)` for better understanding of the object.
The following change was needed.

```
var item = objA ['1'][0];
```

http://jsfiddle.net/rpnzG/